# Web application: showing information with form format

Tags: forms, web-app, information, style

In the place I work (not a company) there's a team developing a Web app. In it, retrieved data information (a school) from a search is displayed as follows:

[image]

As you can see they are using form format to show the data and actual input HTML tags. The CSS style is Bootstrap framework.

I want to discuss with them why they shouldn't do this. From the HTML semantics point of view it should be easy: they are using the wrong tags for what the page is showing (retrieved information to analyze). [HTML inputs are for submitting data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

Now style is not semantics, but one could argue that a something that looks like a form but not behaving like a form only confuses the user. But that's just my reasoning (a sound one I think). So I was wondering if there's something more to it:

Is showing data (In a Web application) with form format a bad practice from the UX point of view?

Answer (score 1):

The main argument against the use of elements without utility in their functionality is that by respecting their formal characteristics, important visual imbalances are produced that obviously affect accessibility.

[image: escalonado]

The dividing line of each entry in the form follows the width of the word title, which causes an absurdity staggered in the alignment of each of the entries. In both design and accessibility, differentiating each element, and standing out from one another, does the UI design job almost without any custom adjustment:

[image]